# Why am I getting the error "the data cannot have more levels than the reference" and "Only strings can be converted to symbols?"

Tags: r, regression, roc, confusion-matrix

I am fairly new to R so excuse me if these are basic mistakes. Here is my code for the question:

```
 install.packages("caTools")
library(caTools)
library(caret)

my_log <- glm(as.factor(quality_binary) ~ fixed.acidity + volatile.acidity + citric.acid + chlorides + free.sulfur.dioxide + total.sulfur.dioxide +
                density + pH + sulphates + alcohol, data = my_type_train, family = "binomial")

prediction = predict(my_log, newdata = my_type_test, type = "response")

### Prediction_Category
predict_cat = ifelse(prediction < 0.5,0,1)
predict_cat

df = data.frame(Predicted = predict_cat, Actual = my_type_test$quality)
df$Predicted = as.factor(df$Predicted)
df$Actual = as.factor(df$Actual)

### Confusion matrix
result =
confusionMatrix(as.factor(df$Actual), as.factor(df$Predicted), positive = "True")
result ### Accuracy is 80%


#### Calculations of Probability
prob=predict(my_log,type=c("response"))
my_type_train$prob=prob

install.packages("cutpointr")
library(cutpointr)
library(pROC)

roc <- roc(quality ~ prob, data = my_type_test)

plot(roc)
auc(roc)

plot(roc) +
  geom_line(data = roc, color = "red") +
  geom_abline(slope = 1) +
  labs(title = "ROC Curve for Logistic Regression")
```

I am getting two errors in this code. My task is to create a ROC curve and calculate AUC Based on test data. **Here are the two errors: Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(Actual), as.factor(Predicted),  : the data cannot have more levels than the reference & Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols.**

**After updating my code with the feedback, I am getting the following errors.
Error in `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = NULL) :
number of levels differs
Error in confusionMatrix.default(df$Predicted, df$Actual) :
The data must contain some levels that overlap the reference.**

Here is my new code:

```
install.packages("caTools")
library(caTools)
library(caret)

my_type_train$quality_binary <- my_type_train$quality_binary

my_log <- glm(as.factor(quality_binary) ~ fixed.acidity + volatile.acidity + citric.acid + chlorides + free.sulfur.dioxide + total.sulfur.dioxide +
                density + pH + sulphates + alcohol, data = my_type_train, family = "binomial")

prediction = predict(my_log, newdata = my_type_test, type = "response")

### Prediction_Category
predict_cat = ifelse(prediction < 0.5,0,1)
predict_cat

df <- data.frame(Predicted = predict_cat, Actual = my_type_test$quality_binary)
df$Predicted <- as.factor(df$Predicted)
levels(df$Predicted) <- levels(df$Actual)
df$Actual = as.factor(df$Actual)

### Confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(df$Predicted, df$Actual)
result ### Accuracy is 80%


#### Calculations of Probability
prob=predict(my_log,type=c("response"))
my_type_train$prob=prob

install.packages("cutpointr")
library(cutpointr)
library(pROC)

roc2 <- roc(quality_binary ~ prob, data = my_type_test)

plot(roc2)
auc(roc2)

plot(roc) +
  geom_line(data = roc, color = "red") +
  geom_abline(slope = 1) +
  labs(title = "ROC Curve for Logistic Regression")
```

Answer (score 2):

For `confusionMatrix`, you need to re-level your `df$Predicted`.

For example, using `iris` data,

```
iris2 <- iris[iris$Species %in% c("virginica", "setosa"),]
iris2$Species <- factor(iris2$Species)
my_log <- glm(as.factor(Species) ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = iris2, family = "binomial")
x <- predict(my_log, newdata = iris2, type = "response")
xx <- ifelse(x < 0.5, 0, 1)

xxx <- data.frame(Predicted = xx, Actual = iris2$Species)
xxx$Predicted <- as.factor(xxx$Predicted)
levels(xxx$Predicted) <- levels(xxx$Actual) # you need this line for confusionMatrix
xxx$Actual <- as.factor(xxx$Actual)

caret::confusionMatrix(xxx$Predicted, xxx$Actual)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

           Reference
Prediction  setosa virginica
  setosa        50         0
  virginica      0        50
                                     
               Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.9638, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.5        
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  
                                     
                  Kappa : 1          
                                     
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         
                                     
            Sensitivity : 1.0        
            Specificity : 1.0        
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0        
         Neg Pred Value : 1.0        
             Prevalence : 0.5        
         Detection Rate : 0.5        
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5        
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.0        
                                     
       'Positive' Class : setosa
```

For `roc`, I'm not sure that you didn't provide any data or an information about yours, but the problem may be caused by `quality` in  `roc(quality ~ prob, data = my_type_test)`. Instead, try  `roc(quality_binary ~ prob, data = my_type_test)`

Comment: Hi, now I am getting the error "in `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = NULL) : 
  number of levels differs"

Comment: @Crystal You should specify in which line that error occurs.

Comment: I am also getting "Error in confusionMatrix.default(df$Predicted, df$Actual) : 
  The data must contain some levels that overlap the reference." After running the confusion matrix

Comment: I have added the new code to my question with the new errors.

Comment: @Crystal As I said, you need to tell me in which line that error occurs or you should provide your data.

Comment: It occurs in lines 18 & 22.